# Firebase Auth - brute force attack prevention

Tags: android, ios, firebase, security, firebase-authentication

We have an Android and iOS apps which we implemented the Firebase Authentication using Email/Password, Facebook and Google Account.

How can we know if Firebase prevent hackers from running a script with a random email and password multiple times in order to hack into our system in the end?

We found out this on Firebase Console -

> Manage sign-up quota
>
> To protect your project from abuse, we limit the number of new
>   Email/Password and Anonymous sign-ups that your application can have
>   from the same IP address. You can request and schedule temporary
>   changes to this quota here.
>
> Current quota per hour: 100

But could not find anything else over the Web and also this is not so clear for SIGN_IN method and no just SIGN_UP as written above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Firebase login is based on provider for example gmail, facebook ... or your own provider which is in charge to prevent this attacks. also you can test it yourself try by your hand to login multiple times with random password and/or email and see what happens

Comment: We do have a provdier for Email/Password which is our backend server ,but the authentication process confirmed first of all with Firebase. Meaning if someone hacks somehow to Firebase with a random Email and password we will let him in our system. We are the next step AFTER Firebase.

Answer (score 4):

The Firebase Authentication service is monitored for abuse. Information about this monitoring and the actions taken on detected abuse is seldom documented though, since the information changes regularly and would be more helpful to abusers than to most developers.

If you think your use-case is being affected by this monitoring or the actions taken upon it, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) with clear details  (i.e. code)on what you're trying to do, and what behavior you seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Tighten quota if you use password-based Authentication

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#apply-restrictions-password-based-auth

> To mitigate against the possibility that someone might misuse an API key to attempt a brute force attack, you can tighten the default quota of the identitytoolkit.googleapis.com endpoints to reflect the normal traffic expectations of your app. Be aware that if you tighten this quota and your app suddenly gains users, you might get sign-in errors until you increase the quota. You can change your project's API quotas in the Google Cloud Console