# Firebase - prevent bot mass signup

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a website as well as a hybrid app relying on Firebase to handle everything. On the register process, there is currently nothing preventing a bot from registering infinite user accounts with a simple loop.

- Does Firebase has a security system to prevent mass registration from the same IP, for example?
- Is there a way to secure this more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limits are [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits), among other things:

> New account creation - 100 accounts/IP address/hour
>   Account deletion - 10 accounts/second

You don't have any way to further limit the system.

Comment: Well it does seems a bit worrying. Anyone can basically overflow your user base, changing IP with a proxy, and getting 100 users in every time... I don't get how it's usable in production.

Comment: If you experience a problem with abuse, contact Firebase support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134344/firebase-auth-brute-force-attack-prevention